# The value of integer property of a concept is not linked or received when used through property macro in a template

Tags: mps

I am very much new to MPS Jetbrains. And, though I followed the shapes tutorial and tried to implement something on the same lines, I am getting a weird bug.

A concept named "print" has an integer property named "data". In the generator file, I have a template "reduce_print" under "reduction rules".

```
template reduce_print 
input print                                          

parameters                                           
<< ... >>                                            

content node:                                        
{ 
 { 
  <TF [System.out.println($[123]);] TF> 
 } 
}
```

The property macro $[123] is node.data from print concept.

The problem is, using the node.data macro always yields 0.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you posted it works just fine for me (and it certainly should).
The problem must be in some detail not mentioned here, I'm afraid. For example, how does the sample usage code look like?